# Checking out private repository on pip install

Tags: python, git, pip

I've been working on an update to a server that requires a private GitHub repository. I can download the repo on my machine, because I'm able to enter a password when prompted. When I try to do this with my server, which is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, I don't have these prompts, so the module from the GitHub repository is not installed. Is there a way for me to provide the username and password in the installing file that I'm using for pip, so I can have the private repo module install successfully?

I'm using the `-e git+<url>#egg=<name>` in my requirements.txt

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH links instead of HTTPS links, like `git@github.com:username/projectname.git` instead of `https://github.com/username/projectname.git`, and use authentication keys instead of a password.

Step by step, you have to:

1. Change URL in `requirements.txt` to `git@...`.
2. Create a key pair for your deployment machine and store it in `~/.ssh/` directory.
3. Add the key to you Github account.

Read the [GitHub help pages](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for more detailed instructions.